# Why didn't Tempests replace Carriers?

Tags: starcraft-2

My understanding is that the Tempest was always intended to replace the Carrier. The Tempest was originally developed for Wings of Liberty and shelved in favor of the tried & true Carrier. When the Carrier saw relatively little use in the Wings of Liberty metagame, the Tempest was brought back for Heart of the Swarm and at one point during the beta replaced the Carrier entirely.

Why did Blizzard opt to leave the Carrier in?

Also, from a balance/tactical perspective, what different roles do they fill?

Comment: "Why did they design it this way?" questions are not a good fit for our format here.

Comment: As @Sconibulus said, these types of questions don't work well, because the only authoritative answers can be provided by the devs.

Comment: I read this question as "Are the roles of the tempest and carrier different" and answered that way - I can edit the question if that is what @ObliviousSage meant.

Comment: @Sconibulus: Is it a legitimate question if there are actual dev comments on why the decision was made? *Note Arremer's answer.*

Comment: @ObliviousSage: No, the answers can't determine whether the question is on-topic or not. =/

Comment: @ObliviousSage You should modify your question then so it should be reopened. You can also state your case on meta.

Comment: @Ullallulloo: Questions that can't be answered authoritatively are bad, I'm not arguing that. But Arremer's answer suggests *this* question **can** be answered authoritatively.

Comment: @ObliviousSage: Yeah, but that has to be knowable by the question itself to let it be on-topic. It would probably be on-topic if you shifted the question to be more about the different roles they fill and less about Blizzard though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what blizzard developer commented on similar question,it answers to why they didn't remove carriers.

> "I think it is VERY unlikely that we will cut Carrier again. It was
>   just not a cool move. If we had followed my first idea of cutting
>   units and replacing them with new units across all 3 races then I
>   think it would be on the list to be cut. But we didn't do that. No
>   other race got any cuts.
>
> To cut JUST Carrier is weird. And a little mean to our Protoss
>   players.
>
> I don't think Tempest and Carrier are currently in conflict. I believe
>   that Carrier is something that (in theory) could be massed. The
>   current Tempest is something that you use strategically in smaller
>   numbers to control the battlefield and force engagement. Or at least
>   that is my current theory. =)"

[Source discussion](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/forum/topic/6794869573)

[More about tempest development](http://starcraft.wikia.com/wiki/Tempest/Development)

Answer (score 1):

The Carrier is great at long range bombardment of targets, however one thing is suffers from is the interceptors get shredded against any kind of local defense. For example, you can siege a Zerg base from a coast where a pack of Hydralisks can't reach the carrier, but they will quickly take out the interceptors making the Carrier quite useless.

Thus the Tempest was born. Being able to target units at extreme (siege) ranges does nicely take over the role of the carrier. However, to balance both the Tempest and the Carrier, the Tempest does significantly little damage for a unit of its cost and tech requirements. This is because it has the main advantage of range. The carrier however still does a good amount of damage but is more effective at closer ranges where the body of the carrier is a more attractive target than the interceptors. These two ships have very different roles as a result.

In the beta, the Tempest did a good amount of damage as an intended replacement for the carrier - however careful balancing has prevented **any** unit in the game from being removed.